# Картинки не отображаются в браузере, имеют размеры равные 0

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome

Здравствуйте! Заполняю таблицу с помощью WebGrid, одна из колонок отведена под кнопки (редактирование, удаление и проч). Кнопки сделаны так:

```
 grid.Column(header: @ViewResources.MasterData.strAction, canSort: false, style: "EmployeeAction",
                            format: @<text>
            @Html.Raw("<a href='#' id='" + item.ID + "' title='" + @ViewResources.MasterData.strEdit + "'> <span class='btn-editChild'> </span> </a>")
            @Html.Raw("<a href='#' id='" + item.ID + "' title='" + @ViewResources.MasterData.strDelete + "'> <span class='btn-deleteChild'> </span> </a>")
            </text>)
```

В стилях:

```
.btn-editChild:before
{
    content: url(../Content/Images/editMin.png);
    text-decoration: none; 
}

.btn-deleteChild:before
{
    content: url(../Content/Images/RecycleBinMin.png); 
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

В браузере получается следующее:

```
<td class="EmployeeAction">
<a href="#" id="3" title="Edit"><span class="btn-editChild">::before</span></a> 
<a href="#" id="3" title="Delete"><span class="btn-deleteChild">::before</span></a>
</td>
```

Но кнопки не видны! Через F12 можно узнать, что размеры картинки равны 0. Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
.btn-editChild:before
{
    content: url(../Content/Images/editMin.png);
    text-decoration: none; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.btn-deleteChild:before
{
    content: url(../Content/Images/RecycleBinMin.png); 
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Почти заработало! Только на разных компах по-разному, на одном в хроме не работает (работает в ie), на другом в хроме работает.

Comment: Попробуйте обновить "не работающие" браузеры.

Comment: Версии последние. Странная ситуация, добавила строчки, рекомендованные выше, сделала паблиш - все работает. Потом добавила еще кнопку (уже четко указав размеры в стилях), паблиш - не работает. Сделала какие-то изменения в стилях, паблиш - заработало. Т.е. стили подгружаются не сразу (?). Что это за чертовщина происходит?

Comment: Могут быть разные причины этого, например когда вы публикуете страницу, проверьте нет ли разницы в debug/release в настройках publish-а и текущего проекта, может еще и кэш браузера создать такую ситуацию, попробуйте очистить его нажатием Ctrl + F5.

Comment: Очистка кэша помогла! Спасибо большое!

Comment: Рад что помог, обращайтесь!